# Fastest way to find and add Integers in List in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a lot of high integers and I want to decrease their processing capacity by adding them to a list and link the integer to the index number of the list.

For example I add the Integer 656853 to a new list. Its Index is 0 now, since it's the first entry. For the next integer I check the list to see if the value already exists. If not, I add the integer to the list. This should be done with multiple integers.

What is the fastest way to find and add integers to a List?

Is it a good idea to sort them, so they are quicker to find?

Comment: How are you going to be using this list in the future?

Comment: `if some_integer not in my_list: my_list.append(some_integer)`, but it seems like, if you're traversing a huge list of input integers (or a stream, or whatever), that you could just do teh cleanup at the point of ingestion. It's unclear what you're asking. Consider providing some [mcve].

Comment: `unique_list = list(set(huge_list_of_integers))`?

Comment: `unique_dict = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(set(huge_list_of_integers))}`?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)(). This will make sure you will have only one entry for given int.

```
int_set = set()
int_set.add(7)
int_set.add(7)
# there is only one 7 in the int set
```

Answer (score 0):

`unique_list = list(set(huge_list_of_integers))`

If you need indexed reference:

```
for i,num in enumerate(unique_list):
    print(i, num)
```

Or map to a dict of index:value:

```
unique_dict = dict(enumerate(set(huge_list_of_integers)))
for i,v in unique_dict.items():
    print(i, v)
```

Dict by value:index:

```
unique_dict = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(set(huge_list_of_integers))}
for v,i in unique_dict.items():
    print(v,i)
```

Comment: Very good solution. Thank you, but how can I access the index of a specific number in a set() ?

Comment: i'm not using a set for the return value. perhaps if you could improve your question with additional detail I could provide more answer.